# Kendo: how do i set the visibility of the command delete button on a selected rows

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, grid

In the example code http://dojo.telerik.com/UVoSUl/2 I hide the Delete button for certain lines.
It is works.

If I then press Edit and then Cancel, the Delete button will appear again.
I tried to hide the button at the event cancel, but the button is generated later.

How can I hide the delete button for certain lines so that it is not displayed again after pressing Cancel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're hiding the buttons with jQuery and it's not a good approach.

Lucky for you, the Kendo Grid widget has the functionality you need built in. You can do it like this:

```
{ command: ["edit", {
    name: "delete",
    visible: function(row) {
        return row.ProductName !== "Chai" && row.ProductName !== "Chang"
    }
}] }
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. It works very well. It is a perfect solution